# Nested ternary statements

Tags: php, if-statement, ternary-operator

I wonder why this works strange. I understand that the difference is grouping, but does it matter in comparison?

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($items as $item) {
   echo ($i == 0) ? 'first_row' : ($i == sizeof($feedbacks)-2) ? 'last_row' : 'none';
   $i++;
}
```

returns

```
last_row
none
none
last_row
```

and

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($items as $item) {
   echo ($i == 0) ? 'first_row' : (($i == sizeof($feedbacks)-2) ? 'last_row' : 'none');
   $i++;
}
```

returns it correctly

```
first_row
none
none
last_row
```

Why is there a difference?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To use an explanation based on your code, a scaled down version would be:

```
for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
   echo $i == 0 ? 'first_row' : $i == 4 ? 'last_row' : 'none';
}
```

In PHP, this is equivalent to writing:

```
for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
   echo ($i == 0 ? 'first_row' : $i == 4) ? 'last_row' : 'none';
}
```

On the first go, `$i` has the value of `0`, so the first ternary returns `'first_row'` and that string is used as the conditional for the second ternary -- which in boolean context evaluates to `true` -- hence `'last_row'` is returned.

If you regroup it:

```
for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
   echo $i == 0 ? 'first_row' : ($i == 4 ? 'last_row' : 'none');
}
```

then the result of the first ternary will not interfere with the second ternary.

Answer (score 5):

From the [official PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary):

> "It is recommended that you avoid "stacking" ternary expressions. PHP's behaviour when using more than one ternary operator within a single statement is non-obvious"

Apparently, even though PHP's ternary operator (and much of its syntax otherwise) is based on C, for some reason PHP decided to [make it left-associative](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php), whereas in C and most other languages based on it, [the ternary operator is right-associative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence):

**C:**

```
$ cat /tmp/foo.c
#include <stdio.h>
void main (void) { printf("%s\n", ( 1 ? "foo" : 0 ? "bar" : "baz" ) ); }

$ gcc -o /tmp/foo /tmp/foo.c; /tmp/foo
foo
```

**Perl:**

```
$ perl -e 'print ( 1 ? "foo" : 0 ? "bar" : "baz" ) . "\n";'
foo
```

**Java:**

```
$ cat /tmp/foo.java
public class foo { public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println( ( true ? "foo" : false ? "bar" : "baz" ) );
} }

$ javac -d /tmp /tmp/foo.java; java -cp /tmp foo
foo
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$ cat /tmp/foo.js
print( 1 ? "foo" : 0 ? "bar" : "baz" );

$ rhino -f /tmp/foo.js
foo
```

**PHP:**

```
$ php -r 'echo ( 1 ? "foo" : 0 ? "bar" : "baz" ) . "\n";'
bar
```

So, yeah, I think we can safely conclude that PHP is just plain ass-backwards in (also) this respect.

Comment: mitigated between upvoting for nice exemples in other languages and downvoting for disregarding php :/

Answer (score 3):

See [example 3 on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php):

```
<?php
// on first glance, the following appears to output 'true'
echo (true?'true':false?'t':'f');

// however, the actual output of the above is 't'
// this is because ternary expressions are evaluated from left to right

// the following is a more obvious version of the same code as above
echo ((true ? 'true' : false) ? 't' : 'f');

// here, you can see that the first expression is evaluated to 'true', which
// in turn evaluates to (bool)true, thus returning the true branch of the
// second ternary expression.
?>
```

The important part being:

> this is because **ternary expressions are evaluated from left to right**

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the answer provided by JRL. To be more clear about what is happening with your example you should understand that your expression is evaluated as such:

```
echo (($i == 0) ? 'first_row' : ($i == sizeof($feedbacks)-2)) ? 'last_row' : 'none';
```

So when `$i == 0` your statement essentially becomes this:

```
echo 'first_row' ? 'last_row' : 'none';
```

Since `'first_row'` evaluates to `true` your `'last_row'` is the result returned when `$i == 0`. When `$i` does not equal zero your statement essentially becomes this:

```
echo ($i == sizeof($feedbacks)-2) ? 'last_row' : 'none';
```